# Repeated measures dual-outcome model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, biostatistics

I have some data that I'm not sure how to analyse. I am testing whether birds prefer to hide food in light or shade. Birds were given the opportunity to place food objects in light or shade, and I then weighed the amount of food in each condition. The experiment was then repeated several times for each bird.

I have calculated the proportion weight of food in each condition for each test, it is not normally distributed. How can I test whether birds place a higher proportion of food in light or shade?

Comment: Are you interested in the number of times they preferred shade to light, or in the total weight of the food stored in each? Is there a reason to think that weight matters? Eg, is there a theoretical reason to think birds might want to store large volumes in shade & small volumes in light? Did you control for the weight of the food you gave them?

Comment: Ideally I want to use weight because they sometimes put food in both areas but only a tiny amount in one and loads in another. Yes I controlled for food weight. I could make the data binomial based on which area had the most food in it, but this doesn't seem ideal. Thanks.